# Log4j for different tomcat workers

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j

I want to configure log4j for different tomcat workers.
I mean, I want to get separate log file for each worker. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In tomcat worker using relative path for logging

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a standard implementation for this. We have one at the company I work for, but that's confidential. However, it's pretty easy to achieve:

extend [`org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/AppenderSkeleton.html) and use a [`ThreadLocal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) of appenders you delegate to

Comment: hi Sean Patrick Floyd where exactly this changes need to be done? is it in log4j.properties file?

Comment: No, create a java class that extends the above class and reference your class in the log4j.properties file